# How to pass message from activemq queue to cxf client rest

Tags: osgi, apache-camel, cxf, activemq-classic, blueprint

I am creating a text message and put it in the activemq queue and i display it in the log. Now i need to pass this message to the cxf rs client to use it in the parameter. I am using blueprint to define the camel routes and cxf client.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
default-activation="eager" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs"
xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 
         http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf 
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
         http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs 
         http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxrs.xsd
         http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security
         http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd
         http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
         http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd">

 <!-- Beans -->

<bean id="myTransform" class="cxfcamel.MyTransform"/>
<bean id="serviceBean" class="cxfcamel.GreetingService" />
<bean id="rsprocessor" class="cxfcamel.RSProcessor"/>



<!-- Web Services -->
<jaxrs:server id="customerService" address="http://localhost:7171  /customers">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref component-id="serviceBean" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>

<cxf:rsClient id="rsClient"
    address="http://localhost:7171/customers/entry-point/register/nosJ"
    serviceClass="cxfcamel.GreetingService">
</cxf:rsClient>


<!-- Camel Routes -->
<camelContext id="camel"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route>
        <from uri="timer://projectTimer?repeatCount=1" />
        <bean ref="myTransform" method="transform" />
        <to uri="activemq:queue:LOG.ME" />
    </route>
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:queue:LOG.ME" />
        <to uri="log:ExampleActiveMQRouterBlueprint" />
    </route>

    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:queue:LOG.ME" />
        <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
            <constant>application/json</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>PUT</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="cxfrs:bean:rsClient" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Can any one help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both routes listen to *activemq:queue:LOG.ME* . A queue in ActiveMQ will consume the message and any other queue will not receive the message. You need to do 1 of 2 things:

1. Turn your queue into a topic so that both routes will receive the message. [Topic vs Queue](http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html)
2. Arrange your routes so only one route is listening to *activemq:queue:LOG.ME*.

---

There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. Turn your cxfrs:bean:rsClient invocation into a cxfrs:http://localhost:7171/customers/entry-point/register/nosJ and append the parameters at the end.
2. The documentation on this isn't very clear, but you might be able to use setHeader:

   `<setHeader headerName="CamelCxfRsQueryMap">
      expression which returns a map
    </setHeader>`

This expression can be `<bean>`, a `<groovy>` embedded expression, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But I want to pass the queue message to URL in CXF RS Client so that I can use it as a Query Param.For Example: http://localhost:7171/customers/entry-point/register/{Queue Message} Can you help me please !!

Comment: Okay! That makes more sense. I'll update my answer. I did not see that information in your original post but I see it now =)

Comment: In my case, I have a Basic Authentication in the cxfrs endpoint like this :<cxf:rsClient id="rsClient"
  address="http://10.47.2.203:8080/rest/api/2/project/TM" serviceClass="cxfcamel.GreetingService" username="username" 
 password="password" >
 </cxf:rsClient>
I think that the first proposal will not work for my case !! Although I don't get the second way !! Should I Declare a bean that contains a Map or what exactly !!